# Purrple screen with broken external video card

Tags: boot, screen

a fresh installation of Ubuntu get's stuck on a purple screen when I try to load it. Restoring broken packages from recovery mode helps for a single session. I tried installing Nvidia graphics driver since my laptop has an external Nvidia card and an integrated intel one. But the Geforce is physically not working and can't be fixed so I get a black screen with Nvidia drivers, had to delete them from root. Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the NVIDIA drivers this way ... I assume you have NVIDIA GEFORCE 400 graphics or newer :

Remove the NVIDIA software you have tried to install.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Install the NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Now adding a boot parameter is not necessary anymore.
Switch between graphics from NVIDIA X Server settings.